# Matlab function to convert a struct to a struct array

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I have a struct in the format of:

```
my_struct
   |
   + element_1
   |     |
   |     + value_1: "some string"
   |     + value_2: 25
   |
   + element_2
   |     |
   |     + value_1: "some other string"
   |     + value_2: 11
   ...
```

and can't find a simple way to create a struct array such that `my_struct(1).value_1 == "some string"`. And similarly, `my_struct(2).value_2 == 11`. The field names "element_1" and "element_2" are unnecessary.

Comment: Did you try a simple loop? `out(ii)=my_struct.(['element_',num2str(ii)]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way (see [`struct2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html) and [`cell2mat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html)):

```
result = cell2mat(struct2cell(my_struct).');
```

**Example**:

```
my_struct.element_1.value1 = "some string"; 
my_struct.element_1.value2 = 25;
my_struct.element_2.value1 = "some other string"; 
my_struct.element_2.value2 = 11;
result = cell2mat(struct2cell(my_struct).');
```

gives

```
>> result
result = 
  1×2 struct array with fields:
    value1
    value2
>> result(1)
ans = 
  struct with fields:

    value1: "some string"
    value2: 25
>> result(2)
ans = 
  struct with fields:

    value1: "some other string"
    value2: 11
```